# Saving JSON received through a controller to the database ASP.Net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core

Hi guys I am new to work in asp.net core  mvc, I had a lot of doubts, Thanks to the Stack Overflow Community I have gained a bit more knowledge. I am trying to POST JSON to the controller and save it to a database using Model Binding.

I am able to POST the JSON to the controller using the following ajax:

```
    $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
        //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
        var customers = new Array();
        $("#tblCustomers TBODY TR").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var customer = {};
            customer.Name = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
            customer.Country = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
            customers.push(customer);
        });

        //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Customer/InsertCustomers",
            data: JSON.stringify(customers),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
            }
        });
    });
```

This is my controller

```
 public JsonResult InsertCustomers(List<Customer> customers)
    {

            if (customers == null)
            {
                customers = new List<Customer>();
            }

            //Loop and insert records.
            foreach (Customer customer in customers)
            {
            _context.Customers.Add(customer);
            }
            int insertedRecords = _context.SaveChanges();
            return Json(insertedRecords);

    }
```

Model:

```
 public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

1. Now I can not understand how to manage my controller 
 2. List item
 3. How can i insert successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is model binding. Since the contentType in your ajax is application/json, the bind data will from the request body. You should apply the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter.

```
public JsonResult InsertCustomers([FromBody]List<Customer> customers)
```

For more details, you can refer to the Offical document of [Model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-attribute)

And the other codes works fine, I have tested, records can be inserted into database succesfully.